# How can I paint over a bitumen floor?

Tags: flooring, paint, outdoor

I have a terrace that has been recently covered with a bitumen based product ([This one, if you can read german](http://www.amazon.de/MEM-Bitumen-Dickbeschichtung-2-K-30/dp/B0037SEGHA)). My problem is that is black and it get's very warm during the day, making it uncomfortable. It also gives a bad chemical smell when it gets very warm. I would like to paint it brighter, but don't know with what. Is there any paint that can hold on top of bitumen? What other options would I have to cover it? I live in an area where it rains and gets below freezing in the winter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems similar enough to "blacktop" (asphalt, tarmacadam, etc...) to apply the advice given in [this greenhouse manual](http://www.greenhouse.cornell.edu/structures/factsheets/pgm.pdf) (page 7) - basically to dust with portland cement (get white rather than gray, if you can find it) and then sprinkle/mist with water. Certainly the product linked appears to be congruent with common driveway blacktop sealer. I have only read the advice in question, not tried it.

[Tennis court toppings](http://www.sportmaster.net/tennis.shtml) should also work, I believe, and are commonly available in green, blue, or red - and possibly many other colors.